# Creating an Availability Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame that contains the values of several parameters against timestamps that are 15 minutes apart. The parameters may contain NaN values(np.nan). My aim is to find the total number of available values per month for each parameter, i.e total number of values in that month that are not 0 or np.nan.

I tried turning all the valid values (values that are not zero or np.nan) into 1; and all the invalid values into 0. That way I can just sum all the values of a parameter in a month and I'd get the total number of available values for that month.

```
df.fillna(0)

for col in selected_parameters:
    df.loc[df[col] > 0, col] = 1
```

This generates the df having 1 for valid and 0 for invalid values.

What I can't do is create a new dataFrame that'll have the timestamps a month apart (instead of 15 min apart) and against each month, I can have the total number of available values for that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a groupby with sum as your aggregator function

```
df.groupby([df.index.dt.year, df.index.dt.month]).agg('sum')
```

This assumes that your timestamps are at the index.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Btw I was using timestamps so didn't have to do a index.dt.  "df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).agg('sum') " worked for me.

Comment: Could I do this in a way that only calculates the sum for only the "selected_parameters" instead of all the non-index parameters ?

Comment: something like this? df[selected_parameters].groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).agg('sum')